# 1969 Toyota Land Cruiser brake bleeding order

Tags: toyota, brakes, land-cruiser

i have a 1969 Toyota Land Cruiser with a single cylinder master cylinder and a single brake line that goes to the left front then goes to the right front then right rear then left rear.

There are 2 wheel cylinders per wheel, one for each brake shoe, and no power brakes.

what is your suggestion on the best routine to bleed the brakes?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the circuit is really as described, then I would start with the cylinder nearest the master cylinder first and work away to the farthest one.

If the pedal is still spongy, I would repeat the process.

NOTE, some "old" master cylinders don't like being "full-stroked" so perhaps a block under the pedal to limit the movement to 2" or so... Some old cylinders will damage, rip or turn seals over as the seals go into the unused portion of the master cylinder.